# How to obtain pairwise comparisons as Significant (S) or Non-significant (N) in Randomised Complete Block Design?

Tags: experiment-design, multiple-comparisons, biostatistics, split-plot

In this problem, I am testing effects of 3 insecticides on a variety of rice. To obtain data, 4 plots have been used (of equal area each). As plots can be different in soil fertility, sheltering from winds, etc., a randomised complete block design (RCBD) approach has been adopted, such that each plot has been subdivided into three rows of each insecticide. Response variable collected is number of weed plants that emerge in each plot. Data obtained is:

[image: Plots are the 'blocks' and insecticide are the 'treatments']

While performing ANOVA, sum of squares of treatments, sum of squares of error, sum of squares of blocks and total sum of squares is calculated, from which F value is determined.

As F-critical calculated from standard tables for alpha = 0.05 is 5.14, it is concluded that treatments are significantly different.

Now it is desired to obtain a 'Significant (S)' or Non-Significant (N)' chart as shown below:

[image]

In the table shown, N stands for Non-significant difference in means and S for significant. The entries have been made randomly, for illustrative purpose only. Output as shown in the table is desired. I am using MS Excel. Please mention how can it be accomplished in Excel. Can it be done using Fisher Least Significant Difference (LSD) approach? If yes, then how?

Comment: I think your design should be called [split-plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_randomization) rather than randomized complete block design.

Comment: @gung Could you give an example using Split-Plot Design where such a table giving significant (S) and non-significant (N) effects has been constructed?